# Skip certain lines and separate by multi delimiters before importing to Excel

Tags: python-2.7

I have a data file that I need certain lines (START TIME & END TIME) skipped and separate "|", "space" and "comma".

[image]

I'm trying to obtain this output:

[image]

Comment: Please add your code showing what you're already doing

Comment: What's the format?